# SharePoint Online - Map crawled properties to managed properties using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, managed-property

I want to **map** **Crawled Properties** to the **Managed Properties** using PowerShell for SharePoint Online. I have created a site column "**ExcludeContent**" and added to the list and now I have Managed Property "**ExcludeContent**" and I want to map it to Crawled Properties  "**ows_ExcludeContent**". I've found **Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty** but it is valid only for **SharePoint Server**.
Can we achieve it using PowerShell ?

Answer (score 1):

According to my research and testing, we cannot build the mapping relationship between crawled properties and managed properties through powershell commands in SharePoint Online.

Beacause the "**Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty**" only for SharePoint Server.

**Reference:**

- [Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spenterprisesearchmetadatamapping?view=sharepoint-ps)