# Sharepoint Online - Map crawled property to managed refinablestring property using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, managed-property

I need to map crawled property to managed refinable string property in sharepoint online using powershell.

I cannot do this through UI interface as I have multiple sites to map. I tried powershell cmdlet like `Get-PnPSearchConfiguration` https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPSearchConfiguration.html , but I cannot find anything which returns me property to map, neither any cmdlet to map the properties.

I checked this link it says through powershell it is not possible https://stackoverflow.com/a/68739248/4549001 , can you suggest any alternative with some sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pipe to select object : | -Property *  The asterisk will give all properties.

Comment: Can you give the entire command, because Get-PnPSearchConfiguration | -CrawledProperties * do not return me anything, may be I am trying incorrectly

Comment: Get-PnPSearchConfiguration | Select-Object -Property *  or Get-PnPSearchConfiguration | Select-Object -Property | Format-List